# How to define referential-integrity in this scenario for 2 SQL Server tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design, foreign-key-relationship, referential-integrity

I have 2 tables in SQL Server 2005 as follows

### Table A

- ActionID (PK,int, not null)
- ProgressID (uniqueidentifier,not null)
- ReferID (uniqueidentifier, not null)
- Field XYZ (varchar(50), not null)
- Field MNO (tinyint, not null)

### Table B

- TrackID (PK,int, not null)
- ProgressID (uniqueidentifier,not null)
- ReferID (uniqueidentifier, not null)
- Field ABC (varchar(20), not null)
- Field EFG (datetime, not null)

Now I have a specific question:

The `ProgressID` in both the tables refer to the same entity. And I want to establish an integral relationship so that Deletion of `ProgressID` in Table A is not possible when value exisits in Table B. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a before delete trigger for this.  Something like

```
create trigger tr_tableA_progressId
on TableA for Delete
as 
    if exists
        (select 'true'
        from dbo.TableB
        where TableB.progressID = (select progressID
                                  from deleted d))

        BEGIN
            RAISERROR 'Cannot delete progressId exists in TableB'
            ROLLBACK TRAN
        End
```

I do not know of a constraint that will enforce what you would like.